# Nested if in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the following formula. Here BC col. has the date on which the formula operates, and it works well.

```
 =IF(AND(BC2>TODAY()-90,BC2<=TODAY()-30),"Settled In",
    IF(AND(BC2>TODAY()-30,BC2<TODAY()),"Happy to be Home",
    IF(AND(BC2>=TODAY(),BC2<TODAY()+30),"Hospital",
    IF(AND(BC2>=TODAY()+30,BC2<TODAY()+90),"third",
    IF(AND(BC2>=TODAY()+90,BC2<TODAY()+195),"second",
    IF(AND(BC2>=TODAY()+195,BC2<=TODAY()+280,"first"))))))
```

But actually the date is present in a string and I get the date using Datevalue formula i.e. (DATEVALUE(MID(AQ2,33,10))). When I replace col BC2 with datevalue, it gives me problem of more number of ifs that are allowed in this format.

Please assist. Thanks!

Comment: Which column gives you the error message??? BC or the Cell that the above formula is in??? Also, can you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So, BC2 is a date that I'm trying to see where it falls, and assigning an appropriate status. But this date is present as a string in another column, and I'm using datevalue to extract the date. When I run the formula it says error on Datevalue MID function and a popup comes up saying, "This formula uses more level of nesting". Using datevalue fn, I'm trying to get date out of a string like this "[{"name": "due date", "value": "2019-08-08"}, {"name": "shipping_interval_frequency", "value": "1"}, {"name": "shipping_interval_unit_type", "value": "Months"}]"

Comment: Worked fine for me - What version of Excel ?   ... I'm 16.0.11231 ....... 32 bit

Comment: based on the sample string ... your mid function should be 34,10 not 33,10

Comment: @user1302114 - Did it work with datevalue fn in it. Could you try the following, instead of BC2 try - (DATEVALUE(MID(AQ2,33,10))) where AQ2 is a string ex "[{"name": "due date", "value": "2019-08-08"}, {"name": "shipping_interval_frequency", "value": "1"}, {"name": "shipping_interval_unit_type", "value": "Months"}]"

Comment: Yes worked with datevalue function ... see mid comment

Comment: gave me second with that string and mid(aq2,34,10)

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments but also adding an answer to eliminate this from list of un-answered questions ..... not looking for brownie points

based on the sample string ... your mid function should be 34,10 not 33,10